# TFS Upgrade from 2010 to 2012 or 2015 Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: tfs, upgrade, tfs-2015

During the upgrade process from 2010 to either 2012 or 2015 I get the following error on just one of my collections "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." It is tied to the Work Item Tracking Step.

The error couldn't be more unspecific and unless there is something I am missing in the upgrade log, they are pretty useless.

Comment: Are you running 2010 SP1 with the last-released Cumulative Update? I believe this was the last CU for TFS 2010: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29078

Comment: Submit a support ticket at Microsoft. This is almost impossible to help debug using the information supplied and likely needs specific scripts to get you out of the pickle that only Microsoft Support or the Product team can provide.

Comment: I can only echo Daniel, make sure TFS 2010 is at the latest SP and CU. Check: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/granth/2012/01/02/tfs-2010-what-service-packs-and-hotfixes-should-i-install/ Also prefer a full server upgrade over an Detach/Attach upgrade

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys, I will check on which CUs or patches have been applied and make sure I am on the latest. I guess my next step would be to contact Microsoft, send them the logs and see if there is anything they can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below things to narrow down the issue:

- Check your TFS server to make sure the machine is not running out of
  disk space.
- Install the [TFS 2010 SP1 Cumulative Update 2 - KB2646719](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29078)
- Try to **Detach and Re-attach** the specific project collection which has the issue.
- Check if there are any projects that has been deleted from TFS but
  without deleting source control folder (Code folder). In this case,
  you can delete the projects by `TFSDeleteProject.exe`, then try it
  again. See [Delete a team project with TFSDeleteProject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfsdeleteproject-cmd?view=tfs-2018) for
  details.

Comment: I know for sure I am not running out of space, I will install CU2 if not already applied. Thankfully I've now virtualized this machine and can try a few things and quickly roll back to my previous snapshot and try again without affecting the original installation.

As far as checking if a project has been deleted from TFS, but still has a code folder, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: @Redmisfitx Basically the project was not deleted completely. You can try to get the project list from web portal, then get project list from DB or via REST API ([Get a list of team projects](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects#get-a-list-of-team-projects)). Then compare the two lists. Generally the projects in the two lists should be the same. If there are extra projects in the list which retrieved via REST API, then you can try to delete them accordingly.

Comment: I ended up using the "TFS Integration" tool and moved projects one by one to the new server/Collection. Microsoft support had me endlessly recreating the issue and trying a bunch of useless configuration changes. I felt they were just throwing things out there until one stuck. I really appreciate the help you guys provided.